# Track record of postgres database of heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku-postgres

I have developed an app in `rails` and have deployed it in heroku and I have used `Postgres` database. Now, as an admin, I want to visualize the current structure of all my tables, i.e., the rows in the table or the data in those rows. I have implemented everything, from collecting the data to storing it in database, and now I want to see the track record of all the data modification that is happening in my tables in my database. kindly guide me.

Comment: please use `gem active admin ` , for tracking the record modification , you can go with this article `https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Auditing-via-paper_trail-%28change-history%29`

Comment: are you looking to view the transaction history in tables. there is no history in database.

Comment: yes I want to see the data.@Bijendra

Comment: Are you asking for a GUI for viewing the database?  I use `pg admin` for that.  You would need to download it and then you would be able to connect it to the heroku postgresql database, but explaining how to do all that would depend on your OS and too many other factors to answer here.  Look at `pg admin`, install it and maybe ask questions from there if a GUI is what you are looking for.